# C function to find largest element in an array of integers

Tags: c, testing

Consider the C function

```
int largest(int list[], int n, int l);
```

- `list` is a list of `n` integers.
- `l` is temp space for the function

The function is supposed to return the largest integer in the list of `n` integers in the array `list`.

```
int largest(int list[], int n, int l) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
      if(list[i] > l) {
         l = list[i];
      }
   }
   return l;
}
```

Why is this function returning bad data at times?

Comment: Function is *returning* bad *input*?

Comment: Please show the "bad data".

Comment: I think I need to get the value at space 'l' instead of comparing to l. any thoughts?

Comment: The `l` argument is pointless.  If it was a pointer, you could usefully write to it.  As it stands, it just gets in the way.  Use a local variable `l` like you do `i`.  Also, you should set `l = list[0];` before starting the loop.

Comment: How do you call your function? Is it a practical application of GIGO?

Comment: Do not destroy your question, especially not after people have provided you with an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you are trying to print the value `l` but you are not actually storing the return value of the function. Also you don't need to pass `l` as a parameter to your function.

Do this instead:

```
   // Declare the function prototype without int l.
   int largest(int list[], int n);

   // Actual function that searches for largest int.
   int largest(int list[], int n) 
   {
      int i;
      int l = list[0]; // Point to first element. 

      // Notice loop starts at i = 1.
      for(i = 1; i < n; i++) 
      {
         if(list[i] > l) 
           l = list[i]; 
      }

      return l;
   }
```

Then where you call your function do this:

```
int l = largest(list, n);
```

This code above just ensures that you store the value that your function returns.

Comment: And if `n` is 0? I'd prefer `int l = INT_MIN; for(i = 0; ...` but some might go for an error message and exit(1).

Comment: May I humbly suggest not using `l` as a variable name.. especially when `1` and `i` are nearby!

Comment: @rici you make a very smart point. I hope OP cares enough about his question to understand the possibilities. And Matt, I normally would not use `l` I completely understand how much `1` and `l` look alike! I wanted to be consistent for the OP though.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `l`, so it will return the existing value of this if none of the items in the list were larger than it. If you never initialized it in the calling function then the behaviour is undefined, which would explain your "bad data".